# Remove the windows.old folder after it has already been deleted

Tags: windows-7, windows.old

When I upgraded from Windows Vista to Windows 7, I copied all of my files back over from the Windows.old folder. When I was done I deleted the Windows.old folder with the deleted key and then deleted it from my recycle bin. This was about 2 months ago. I recently found out that there was a process to removing that folder. What do I do now? Im sure the files have already been overwritten so is there anything that I should do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such "process" - I did the same thing when I changed my laptops / moved from Vista - and haven't faced any problems.

Comment: The process that I am talking about is using the Disk Cleanup tool to remove the old operating system and files

Comment: ah, that. That doesn't do anything special @muckdog

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to the advanced version?

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Cmd.exe /c Cleanmgr /sageset:65535 & Cleanmgr /sagerun:65535
```

It doesn't clean stuff related to `windows.old` but it might be what you are looking for.

Watch out what you select there though...